# On react-native-track-player background mode not working on IOS version 13 & above

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-track-player

I am using react-native-track-player version 2.0.3

Issue : Sometimes when i minimize the app, the song is playing on background after completing one song next song is not playing automatically on physical device.[Xcode background mode setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o52E.png)

IDEs:

```
Android Studio: 2020.3 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292
Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
```

Languages:

```
Java: 1.8.0_292 - /usr/bin/javac
```

npmPackages:

```
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
react-native: 0.66.0 => 0.66.0
```